# If A and C are independent random variables, calculating the pdf of AC using two different methods

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution

Suppose $A$ and $C$ are uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ and are independent random variables. Then, I found the pdf of $AC$ using this method:

$$f_{AC} (a,c) = f_A (a) f_C(c) =  \begin{cases} 
                                   1 & 0 \le a,c \le 1 \\
                                   0 & {\text{otherwise}}
                                  \end{cases}
$$

> **However, if I try to find it in the following manner:**

Suppose $K = AC \implies F_K(k) = \int~ _{K \le d} \int f_K(k)~dK = \int~_{AC \le k} \int 1 \cdot dA ~dC$

$$=\int_0^k \int_0^1 dC ~dA ~+~\int_k^1 \int_0^{\frac{k}{a}} dC~dA = k - \ln k$$

Differentiating , we get $f_K(k) = - \ln k$

**Are both these answers right?**

Comment: Your $f_{AC}$ is incorrect (assuming by "$AC$" you mean the product of the variables $A$ and $C.$)

Comment: @whuber Thank you... aah I think i did a fundamental mistake there